# Парсинг и маппинг динамического объекта

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Всем привет. Извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но не могу понять, как правильно замаппить указанный ниже json в какую-то модель. Т.е. объект Result может быть разным в зависимости от запроса.
Допустим есть модель Response:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Version {get;set;}
    public int StatusCode {get;set;}
    public object Result {get;set;}
}
```

И есть response:

```
{
    "Version":"1.2.3",
    "StatusCode":200,
    "Result":
    {
        "Id":42,
        "QuestionText":"This is a test question",
        "QuestionImageUrl": "http://www.blah.com/test.png"
    }
}
```

Если выполнить данную операцию, то Result будет типа object, возможно ли его как-то замаппить в нужную модель?

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

Comment: А каким образом можно узнать, какой именно тип результата придёт? Или только глядя на сам результат?

Comment: А если так: `public dynamic Result {get;set;}`..? но, конечно, согласен с VladD, тип результата желательно знать.

Comment: Результат всегда имеет одинаковую структуру?

Comment: при работе с json его всегда можно маппить на Dictionary, в данном случае так же можно использовать `JObject`

Answer (score 0):

В .NET для работы с JSON чаще всего используются не встроенные средства, а пакет Newtonsoft.Json.

В нем, конечно же, этот случай предусмотрен.
Создавая экземпляр Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer, Вы можете указать такие параметры, как TypeNameHandling и TypeNameAssemblyFormat, которые позволяют настроить сериализацию информации о типе сериализуемого объекта.
Всё остальное библиотека сделает сама.

Если же вы знаете, какой тип к Вам придет, еще на этапе компиляции, Вы можете просто использовать дженерик-метод Deserialize без предварительной настройки.